# Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined importing mongoose script

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, import

Random errors occurs from nodes_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js
Very strange, every times i run the script the errors happens on a different line of my json import. My json file is valide, i can import it directly from the mongodb shell. However i still need to pass my file through my middlewares so i need that forEach of my document execute Model.create() from my script. Anyone experienced that crazy moment too?

My very basic script

```
// Import data to database
const importEntries = async() => {
    try {
        await oldEntries.forEach(async(entry, index) => {

            entry.amount = entry.amount.replace(',', '.')

            if (entry.amount.startsWith('-')) {
                entry.amount = entry.amount.replace('-', '')
                entry.flow = 'expense'
            } else {
                entry.flow = 'income'
            }
        })
        fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/new-entry.json`, JSON.stringify(oldEntries, null, 2))

        await Entry.create(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/new-entry.json`, 'utf-8')))
        console.log("Entries imported successfully");

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    process.exit()
}
```

Comment: `forEach(async(entry, index) =>` this is not a valid code. I mean it will still run but it will not do what you are expecting it to do. [https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404).

Comment: @decho how should i right it correctly?

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but you can use what is called [for await of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of). so instead of `await oldEntries.forEach(async(entry, index) => {` you can try `for await (entry of oldEntries) {`.